# How do I know if my AC recycle Air instead of bringing air from outside?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have an AC unit at home: [image: AC]
and I'm wondering if it can be used to improve the air quality indoors. My concern is whether the AC unit brings in air from outside, which may not be ideal for air quality.

I would like to know if this specific AC model brings in outside air or if it only circulates and filters the existing indoor air.

Comment: what is the model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recirculating is far more energy-efficient, and is the primary mode for most AC.

The exceptions generally have an explicit control labelled "vent" or something like that, to allow outside-air intake to be turned on and off. And that intake is usually fairly minimal, again for efficiency's sake.

If you want fresh air, consider turning off the AC and opening a window when outside temps are close to desired inside temp (eg overnight), or installing a Heat Recovery Ventilation (HRV) system which tries to use the air being exhausted to pre-heat or pre-cool the air being brought in.

(Or just turn on an exhaust fan and count on air leakage into the building to make up the difference, but that's less efficient than HRV and may not work well in highly sealed buildings.)

Comment: I think the OP does not want fresh(smog, smoke) outside air to come in in the first place.

Comment: If that's the goal, the unit they've got is Just Fine.

Comment: @keshlam assuming it has a filter and that filter is relatively new!

Comment: @Huesmann That's a different question than the one that was asked.

Comment: @keshlam but it clarifies the response to the question that was asked...